# SwiftUI builds successfully but preview fails

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm on the latest OS and Xcode version (11.2) and for some reason my canvas just will not build. I keep getting `X is not a member of PROJECT` error. It's driving me insane. It was working not that long ago and I have no idea what changed to make it fail like this. I've also tried deleting Derived Data, restarting laptop...

I've made sure that all my files are included in my target and everything looks like it should be working properly, the app itself builds perfectly fine it's just the preview

Comment: It is hard to say anything without code, can you provide some example? Have you tried it with previous Xcode version (you can download 11.1 and unpack it in different location)?

Comment: @Asperi It seems like no matter which file I try to preview it doesnt work. And if I start removing the problematic files one by one it still doesn't work. For instance if it's telling my LoginView is not a member of my project and then delete it, it will tell me another view is not a member

Comment: I use Version 11.2 (11B52) and did not observe such issue at all. Ok, relaunch Xcode w/o opening your project, create empty SwiftUI project and try to just build it and preview default ContentView. With this at least you'll be sure that Xcode works properly.

Comment: @Asperi Yes is does work for the new project. I can't imagine what is wrong with my current one that the project builds fine on the simulator but not the preview. The error message is not helpful in the slightest

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue. I created a new project, and the preview of the default ContentView works fine. But the issue presents itself again as soon as I add files from my other project to the new project. Nothing previews. I'm still looking for a solution

Comment: @clayzar See my answer

Comment: Now in Xcode 13.2.1, creating a new project with 'Hello world' keeps failing. Cannot get it to work. None of the project now shows preview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to my problem was that I had a file within my project named the same as my project name. The error messaging was not useful at all in solving this, but once I had renamed that file, the preview began working again.

Comment: Had the same issue. Exactly helped!

Answer (score 4):

So I had this same issue except I found out it was because I have custom build configurations and it didn't like the custom module name Xcode made. The solution was to rename the module to the same thing as debug and release in **Build Settings > Product Module Name**

I hope this helps someone

Comment: Thanks, buddy, this was exactly my issue!